# Face scanner usage with CM 10.1 on Galaxy s3 i9300

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, custom-roms

I'm running CyanogenMod 10.1 ( cm-10.1-20130105-NIGHTLY-i9300.zip ) on a Samsung Galaxy S3 i9300, and I want to know if CM 10 supports the face scanner for things like screen on-time and setting passwords. If so, how do I access it?

Comment: There's only FaceUnlock (you can enable it the usual way in *Settings->Security->Screenlock*. Screen-on-time doesn't ring a bell, I assume this is one of the many Samsung addon (vendor specific addons aren't preserved in general with CyanogenMod)